# Fail to install squid on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, squid, webmin

I try to install squid proxy on Raspbian, from Webmin but, after installed successfully, can't configure the module to start using it.

```
The command squid was not found on your system. Maybe it is not installed, or the module configuration is incorrect.
```

I can go to the module configuration page but it doesn't save the file.
Save button throws no error but the file is not saved at /etc/squid3/squid.conf and there is not folder /etc/squid3

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing the location of config to `/etc/squid/squid.config` at the module configuration page.

It seams to be a bug, i installed squid3 by Webmin but seams the config file is still located on old squid config folder.